# Cosmos DB Emulator not working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

On my local win10 pc everything works fine, but I am having issues installing/running the Cosmos DB Emulator on our server 2016 dev box.
The explorer says “Congratulations! Your DocumentDB emulator is running.” Rather than “Congratulations! Your Azure Cosmos DB emulator is running.”
Also, the options to create a New collection, documents, settings etc are all missing, I just get an empty explorer window.

I am using the latest “Azure Cosmos DB.Emulator.msi” and installing as administrator

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: no error in explorer or windows event viewer that i can see

Comment: did you setup an account?

Comment: for the emulator?

Comment: yes to create documents etc

Comment: you don't need an account for the emulator '

Answer (score 2):

Andrew and I worked together and resolved this issue in e-mail. Andrew was able to download a zipped data explorer update from

- https://aka.ms/documentexplorerv1

and extract it to

- $env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\DataExplorer

**Diagnosis**

On startup the Emulator issues a request to download and update the data explorer. This request can fail for all the same reasons that any request can fail. In this case we found that the Emulator's data explorer updater was trying to use something other than TLS1.2; the only version of TLS enabled on Andrews Windows Server machine.

The updater is a .NET Framework app and hence takes a dependency on the .NET Framework libraries installed on the system. We suspect but did not confirm that the updater could not negotiate up to TLS1.2 as a result of the .NET Framework version installed on the system.

By running the updater manually Andrew saw that its update request failed with this exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DocumentDB.DataExplorerUpdater.Program.GetRemoteMD5()
```

**Running the data explorer updater manually**

To diagnose data explorer updater options on your own, issue these PowerShell commands to run the data explorer updater manually:

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\DataExplorer" -Include DataExplorer.hash, installation_id.txt -Recurse | Remove-Item
Set-Location "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\DataExplorerUpdater\DataExplorerUpdater.Code"
.\DocumentDB.DataExplorerUpdater.exe
```

As a fallback, you can download the current data explorer update from:

- https://aka.ms/documentexplorerv1

and then extract it to:

- $env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\DataExplorer